# How to install Haskell Platform 2013.2.0.0 on Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, haskell

I want to use [Haskell Platform](http://www.haskell.org/platform/) 2013.2.0.0 on Ubuntu 13.04.

Because there is no binary package provided, I have to compile it manually.  However, there is a problem.  Ubuntu repo provides GHC 7.6.2, but the Haskell Pratform requires GHC 7.6.3 to compile it, which is newer.  Therefore, I also have to compile and install GHC 7.6.3.

I am currently using GHC 7.6.2 and afraid such manual installation would mess up my environment.

My question is, what is the best and the safest way to install Haskell Platform 2013.2.0.0?

Comment: I want to know about version 2013.2.0.0 of Haskell Platform, which is newer than what @Mitch refers to.

Comment: This is in fact essentially a duplicate of the question cited by @Mitch. If you want to run Haskell Platform 2013.2, some suggestions are: 1) uninstall GHC 7.6.2 and build 7.6.3; 2) keep 7.6.2, but install Haskell and GHC 7.6.3 into your Home; 3) if you have the space, make a separate 13.04 install for Haskell development and do the builds there.